# VBScript asks me to overwrite Excel file despite DisplayAlerts = False

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to run a macro from an Excel file via VBScript, so that I can run that script via Task Scheduler.

That part works, but when it tries to save the file it always asks "File already exists, want to overwrite? Yes, No, Cancel".

While researching, every thread says set DisplayAlerts to False, which I already did but that does not work. If I only use .Save then it saves it to my default Documents Directory - not the sharepoint.

```vb
strPath = "\\ecs.zspi.company.de@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Folder\Test.xlsm" 

strMacro = "VV.VVImport2" '  

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True   
objApp.DisplayAlerts = False
objApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
objApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
objApp.FeatureInstall = msoFeatureInstallNone

Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro 
wbToRun.SaveAs "\\ecs.zspi.company.de@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Folder\Test.xlsm" 
wbToRun.Close False
objApp.Quit
```

It should save the file to the original location without alerting. But I always get the Alert Box "File already exists, want to overwrite? Yes, No, Cancel".

Comment: Why do you use SaveAs when saving to the same file? Can't you use simple Save?

Comment: If I use .Save then it saves the file to my local directory and not the sharepoint.

Comment: why would he be doing that? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Could be something my company configured. Our Documents directory is a network drive. It's integrated as T:\Documents. This way we can Login on any company pc and have our data. I guess some system path is configured that way.

Comment: @GeertBellekens in my case the file with the macro was a "master file" that was running every day. SaveAs was required to save the output of the macro as `.xlsx` without ever modifying the "master file". The "master file" was also completely blank before it started running.

Comment: You could try `wbToRun.Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, based on a comment in another thread.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the first sentence in the third paragraph of the question says _While researching, every thread says set DisplayAlerts to False_

Comment: @reportgunner But the comment that I was referring to indicates referencing the `worbook` object, which he does not do.  He only references the `Application` object.

Comment: Nono, `wbToRun.Application` will return the parent `Application` the `wbToRun` is running in. If there is only one `Application` running then `Application` returns the same thing like `wbToRun.Application`. But maybe I see your point, if OP is calling this from another Excel instance it might help. I remember though that this "bug" was there and DisplayAlerts = False were not enough

Comment: @reportgunner And he is creating an Excel application in his code, so it is possible that he has multiple application instances running.  Of course, even if the alert is suppressed, it is unclear to me, without testing, whether the file will actually get written.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld we are pretty much on the same page. In OP's code I can see `Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)` so `wbToRun` is bound to be a child of `objApp` and therefore setting `DisplayAlerts = False` on `objApp` is the same like on `wbToRun.Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `.Saved` property of the workbook to `True`

```
...
wbToRun.SaveAs "\\ecs.zspi.company.de@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Folder\Test.xlsm" 
wbToRun.Saved = True
wbToRun.Close False
objApp.Quit
```

It seems like the `SaveAs` method doesn't set the property to `True`, I've experienced this problem before and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No more alert comes but sadly it now says Test.xlsm is read-only. Seems like I can't use SaveAs at all.

Comment: What do you mean it's read-only ? You are closing the workbook anyway so why would that be an issue ?

Comment: Ah sorry. I directly translated it from german. I means it is write-protected. Like it can't save it to that path because that file is already open. I get the error code 800A03EC

Comment: close the file or save it with a different name, there's no way getting around that.

Comment: or try with `C:\temp` first instead.

Comment: It's not the most elegant solution but it works now. I name it different, delete the old file and rename the new one to the old file. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is to have the file with the macro in the folder where it is and have the SaveAs point to an `Export` sub-folder. You can then configure the file with the macro to load the last file from the `Export` sub-folder in case you need to append the data in the next run. If you need to have unique names of the export files every time, just put a timestamp in the filename (i.e. `2019-06-21` for today, add time too if you run more than once per day)

Comment: Yeah, normally this is what I would do. But the people who will be working with the data want it as one file. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hmm I see. Sorry I have no experience in using this with Sharepoint.